# How to compress image to be sent through HttpUrlConnection from applet to controller?

Tags: java, spring, applet, http-compression

I addressed a problem with compress an image scanned by ScuGen Finger print sent through HttpUrlConnection from applet to controller, the code seems to be working but I need advise about it.

Here is the code in the applet when I click on Verify FingerPrint Image Button:

```
    BufferedImage img1gray = new BufferedImage(deviceInfo.imageWidth, deviceInfo.imageHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
    float imageQuality = 0.5f;

    Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg");
    if (!writers.hasNext()){
        throw new IllegalStateException("No writers found");
    }else{
        ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter) writers.next();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(baos);
        writer.setOutput(ios);
        ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
        param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
        param.setCompressionQuality(imageQuality);
        writer.write(null, new IIOImage(img1gray, null, null), param);
        byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
        HttpURLConnection connection = getHttpUrlConnection(data);
        PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        outputStream.write("image="+Base64.encodeBase64String(data)+"&index="+String.valueOf(jComboBoxFPIndex.getSelectedItem()));
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                 response.append(inputLine);
             }
            this.jLabelStatus.setText(response.toString());
        }else{
            this.jLabelStatus.setText("Response Code = "+responseCode);
        }
    }
    /*OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(data);*/
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

and Here is the controller where I received the image:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/verifyfingerprint", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String verifyFingerPrint(HttpServletRequest request) throws BusinessException, IOException {
    Loggers.logger.info("Verify Finger Print Image Start");
    Loggers.logger.debug("Usertype = "+attribute.getType());
    String message;

    String fingerPrintImage = request.getParameter("image");
    String fingerPrintIndex = request.getParameter("index");
    if(fingerPrintImage == null || "".equals(fingerPrintImage)){
        message = getResourceMessageHandler().getMessage("verify.finger.print.image.invalid", new String[]{}, Locale.ENGLISH);
        Loggers.logger.error(message);
        return message;
    }

    if(fingerPrintIndex == null || "".equals(fingerPrintIndex)){
        message = getResourceMessageHandler().getMessage("verify.finger.print.index.invalid", new String[]{}, Locale.ENGLISH);
        Loggers.logger.error(message);
        return message;
    }

    FingerPrintValidationRequest fingerPrintValidationRequest = getRegistrationService().prepearFingerPrintValidationRequest(attribute, fingerPrintImage, fingerPrintIndex);
    RestBuilder builder = RestBuilder.getInstance(null);
    AjaxResult ajaxResult = builder.validateFingerPrintImage(fingerPrintValidationRequest,attribute,getRegistrationService(),getResourceMessageHandler());
    Loggers.logger.debug(ajaxResult.toString());
    message = ajaxResult.getMessage().get(0);
    Loggers.logger.info("Verify Finger Print Image End");
    return message;
}
```

Comment: "code seems to be working but I need advise about it" could you add more details to that? Advice about what?

Comment: thanks for replay, advise on the code of image compression, How I can sure that the compression is done successfully?

Comment: When there is no exception thrown? Not sure what you mean. PS: you can [edit] your question and add missing details.

Comment: Is the problem the compressed size of the image? You want to make it less bytes? Agree with @zapl that your question is not clear.

Comment: OK, I will clarify the problem.
in the verify button I checked the match of scanned image with existing one stored in the database, but for every time I got no matching finger print, that is, I want to know if the problem in the compression process

Comment: Tip: Add @zapl (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. Try transmitting the image as PNG, which is an exact representation of the original image. But note: I expect matching fingerprints requires sophisticated image analysis, rather than pixel by pixel comparison. How are the images being compared?

Comment: @AndrewThompso, I will try to use PNG, but I think that the technique of the compression used in the applet differs from one used in the decompression process in the controller. Is this may affect?

Comment: In case the controller uses only jpg increase the quality. `float imageQuality = 0.5f;` means 50% and is fairly low with lots of artifacts. 1.0f is the maximum. When higher quality doesn't work, maybe the images in the database have the same issue and you need to replace them with better ones?